# Venmo: "user does not have a funding fund selected" despite a linked and verified bank account

Tags: android-10

I use the Venmo application to make online payments. I have a bank account linked to my Venmo account. The account is verified. However when I tried to pay online it says "user does not have a funding fund selected". Why?

[image: image of "user does not have a funding source selected" error message]

I use the latest Venmo app on Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

---

Screenshot showing that my bank account is linked + verified (since it doesn't say "unverified"):
[image: screenshot showing bank linked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up up installing the [splitwise Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Splitwise.SplitwiseMobile&hl=en_US&gl=US), which gave me more information regarding the payment issue with Venmo: the connection with my Bank of America account had been "lost" and Venmo need to reconnect to it via [Plaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaid_(company)) (even though the Venmo hadn't previously said that the Bank of America account needed verification).